# FlipSwitch jQuery mobile constructor

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I'm looking for a way to build a new FlipSwitch control inside a container: `<div id="container"/>`

If I run `$("#container").flipswitch({ onText:"Stay", offText:"Go"});`
the HTML that gets generated is:

```
<div class="ui-flipswitch ui-shadow-inset ui-bar-inherit ui-corner-all">
    <a class="ui-flipswitch-on ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-inherit" href="#"/>
    <span class="ui-flipswitch-off"/>
    <div class="ui-flipswitch-input" id="container" tabindex="-1"/>
</div>
```

which doesn't contain my onText/offText labels.

Do I need to manually create the `input` or `select` HTML element inside my container or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First create the input element that will become the flipswitch, then append it to the container div, and finally initialize the widget:

```
var html = '<input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip-checkbox-1">';
$("#container").append(html).find("input").flipswitch({ onText:"Stay", offText:"Go"});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jyx8yhwh/)**